# Select particular listbox value on start of Dynpro?

Tags: listbox, abap, dynpro

I have a custom dialog dynpro including an input field named `DYN_MATNR` as listbox for which I have included a list of particular materials as selection.

How can I set a specific material (of that list) as selected when the dialog dynpro is opened?

PBO of dialog dynpro:

```
  data lt_values type vrm_values.

  select  matnr,
          maktx
    into  table @data(lt_materials)
    from  makt
    where matnr in @so_matnr
      and spras = 'D'
    order by matnr.

  loop at lt_materials assigning field-symbol(<material>).
    append initial line to lt_values assigning field-symbol(<value>).
    <value>-key  = <material>-matnr.
    <value>-text = <material>-maktx.
  endloop.

  call function 'VRM_SET_VALUES'
    exporting
      id              = 'DYN_MATNR'
      values          = lt_values
    exceptions
      id_illegal_name = 1
      others          = 2.
  if sy-subrc <> 0.
    " ...
  endif.
```

This works and it shows the list of materials as listbox values. To select a particular material I have included the FM `DYNP_VALUES_UPDATE` afterwards and also in PBO but this did not work:

```
  data lv_stepl type syst-stepl.

  call function 'DYNP_GET_STEPL'
    importing
      povstepl        = lv_stepl
    exceptions
      stepl_not_found = 1
      others          = 2.
  if sy-subrc <> 0.
    " ...
  endif.

  data(lt_dynpfields) = value dynpread_tabtype(
   ( fieldname  = 'DYN_MATNR'
     stepl      = lv_stepl
     fieldvalue = gcl_helper->get_matnr( ) " matnr which should be selected is stored here
     fieldinp   = space )
  ).

  call function 'DYNP_VALUES_UPDATE'
    exporting
      dyname               = sy-repid
      dynumb               = sy-dynnr
    tables
      dynpfields           = lt_dynpfields
    exceptions
      invalid_abapworkarea = 1
      invalid_dynprofield  = 2
      invalid_dynproname   = 3
      invalid_dynpronummer = 4
      invalid_request      = 5
      no_fielddescription  = 6
      undefind_error       = 7
      others               = 8.
  if sy-subrc <> 0.
    " ...
  endif.
```

I am also not able to directly set `DYN_MATNR` as it is not available in PBO.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it:

You need to additionally define a global(!) variable with the name and (wished) type of the input field (e.g. in the top include of the report or in a separate include of the dynpro logic):

```
data dyn_matnr type matnr.
```

Then you can set the initial value of the dynpro field in PBO directly:

```
dyn_matnr = gcl_helper->get_matnr( ).
```

As this becomes rather irritating when using various dialog dynpros I recommend including the dynpro number in those variables and input fields.

Comment: yep, and you also must have [TABLES](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-us/abenabap_dynpros_fields.htm): `When dynpro fields are defined with reference to flat structures in ABAP Dictionary, the global data objects with the same name of the ABAP program must be declared with the statement TABLES as interface work area. Otherwise, there will be no data transport`